# Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 switching Visual Basic to Visual C++

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've installed successfully Visual Studio 2010. Initially,I chose from start-up list (when I launched Visual Studio, the list shows Visual C++,Visual C#,Visual Basic,etc.).

I've chosen Visual Basic. I created project,I programmed and I closed the project and after that, I closed Visual Studio.

When I want to start Visual Studio with same list (I want to be in Visual C++ mode) it doesn't appear and Visual Studio redirects me automatically to Visual Basic mode.

What should I do to select a different mode in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 5):

You mean you set the Visual Studio Environment to Visual Basic. You now need to set to VC++

I think you will need to reset the Environment Settings. To do that:

1. Open Visual studio.
2. Go to -> **Tools** -> **Import Export Settings...**
3. Select **Reset All Settings**.Press **Next**.
4. Select **Yes save my current settings** and press **Next**.
5. Select the desired Environment settings.
6. Press Finish.